# Is it possible to continue using an to external monitor when closing the lid on a Macbook Air?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, display, sleep-wake

I have an application I use on an external monitor with an external USB device.

Is there a way to close the lid and continue using the app on the external monitor?

I turned off the sleep upon close function, but the external monitor still turns off.

OSX 10.9.5

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, its called "closed clamshell" mode. In short, you'll need to attach your MBA to a mouse, a keyboard and power:

https://support.apple.com/HT201834

Comment: I've used clamshell mode on a MacBook Air without problem - just follow the instructions in the above link and everything should work fine.

Comment: According to the posted link, the requirement is an "External keyboard, mouse, *or* trackpad" (emphasis mine). I use my MacBook Pro with an external mouse but without an external keyboard in closed clamshell mode all the time.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, I think keeping the power on here is the key. When I remove the magsafe from my MBP it automatically goes to sleep and turns off the external display.

If you really want to keep it from sleeping even when you are not connected to an external power source, you can use InsomniaX or Caffeine.