# Command-line stop MacBook from sleeping when lid is closed?

Tags: macbook-pro, terminal, macos

I've used Caffeine before and it can stop my MacBook from sleeping when the lid is closed (sometimes I want to continue listening to something through headphones while moving around)

Is there a command that can be run from the terminal that will do the same thing?

I've tried `caffeinate` but it does nothing. InsomniaX does stop the MacBook from sleeping when the lid is closed, is there a way to implement this same functionality from the terminal though?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Disable Sleeping when the lid is closed running on battery

`sudo pmset -b sleep 0; sudo pmset -b disablesleep 1`

Re-enable sleeping when the lid is closed running on battery

`sudo pmset -b sleep 5; sudo pmset -b disablesleep 0`

Remember to re-enable or manually sleep your machine before putting it into a bag.
It will get very hot very quickly in an enclosed space.

Comment: What is the purpose of `sudo pmset -b sleep 0` and `sudo pmset -b sleep 5` before the sleep disabling/enabling commands?

Comment: I can't find any mention of `disablesleep` in `man pmset` on macOS Monterey, why is that?

Answer (score 0):

No. Only setting up closed clamshell conditions will prevent sleep when the proximity sensor indicates the lid is closed.

- [How to keep MacBook awake with lid closed + extended display?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/261320/how-to-keep-macbook-awake-with-lid-closed-extended-display)
- [Is it possible to continue using an to external monitor when closing the lid on a Macbook Air?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/195674/is-it-possible-to-continue-using-an-to-external-monitor-when-closing-the-lid-on/)

Short of finding a way to modify the firmware or unload / set [some hidden arguments to disable sleep](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/152777/how-to-disable-clamshell-mode-in-yosemite), the most viable solution might be hoping that power nap “dark wakes@ allow you to get whatever actions done while “sleep” conditions are present.

Comment: How does Caffeine/InsomniaX do it?

Comment: @theonlygusti -  InsomniaX doesn't seem to be working since El Cap. and newer and as far as I know Caffeine never worked with the lid (it also doesn't work now)

Comment: @Allan InsomniaX still works perfectly for me, I just tried after seeing [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/256414/150109) that claimed it worked. However, InsomniaX is not a perfect solution for me, I'd much rather have a way to do this from the command line without needing to install an entire application.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing shell commands on terminal every time create a bash script.

```
#!/bin/bash
sleepvar="$(pmset -g | grep SleepDisabled)"
sleepval="$(grep -c 0 <<< $sleepvar)"
if [ "$sleepval" -eq 1 ];
    then 
        sudo pmset -b sleep 0; sudo pmset -b disablesleep 1
        #echo "SleepDisabled set to 0, setting to 1 i.e. Disabling sleep"
    else
        sudo pmset -b sleep 1; sudo pmset -b disablesleep 0
        #echo "SleepDisabled set to 1, setting to 0 i.e. Enabling sleep"
fi
```

save it as `<filename>.command` , give it execution permissions using `sudo chmod +x <filename>.command`

after execution, use `cmd+q` to close the terminal,

or **to close automatically**:

open terminal-> open "Terminal" menu -> Settings-> Shell -> open "when the shell exits" dropdown -> choose "close if the shell exited cleanly"

or you can alternatively **create AppleScript Application for a more UI friendly experience**,
I have posted the steps here.

https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/462512/501809

Comment: That’s just an AppleScript wrapper for shell commands.  You can put a shell script (or link to it) on your desktop and double click that the same way.

Comment: @Allan yes it is shell script , i tried what you are suggesting and after failing to run sudo commands, i later moved to Applescript wrapper. Applescript application makes it convenient to input your password.

Comment: `sudo` will stop execution and wait for a password.  To make it seamless , you [modify the `sudoers`](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/461818/119271) to allow that command to run with no password.  It’s accomplished with 1/10th the code.

Comment: @Allan Thanks for making me aware about sudoers file.
Surely one can put the efforts in modifying the sudoers file and get rid of 3 extra lines to create Applescript wrapper around the shell script , although 1/10th of the code seems and exaggeration.

Comment: `pmset -g | grep SleepDisabled` doesn't return anything on my MBA?

Comment: @nohillside strange! it works for my MBA(M1).